# How to add checkboxes with possibility to choose all in datatable jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I work wit library [datatables](https://datatables.net/), and i want to add in table row check box for some actions, i add checkboxes to the table,and one check box in table header for choose all boxes.

Script:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
    $(':checkbox.checkbox-mark').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

In [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/q5xw20ct/1/) you can see more.

But problem is, i have pages, and in case if i tap on header checkbox, it's choose only all boxes in curent page, but i want in the all pages, how i can solve this?

Comment: @Dejan.S yes it's make sense, but i try few methods to do this, but i the end no result

Comment: @Dejan.S i work only with front-end, okay, but anyway in case if i go in page 2 or  3 and i tap choose all, it;s chose all in first page

Comment: @Dejan.S yes we have back-end developers, and we separate job, and i have task to add this checkboxes

Comment: I'm sorry I miss read the question. Let me check the dataset real soon, shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you discussed already you can use service/api to set selectAll values but if you want to it using front end then you can use `DataTable().cells().nodes();` to get all the nodes and iterate through them and set the checkbox value to each node.

```
// update your checkAll logic like this

$('#checkAll').click(function() {
  var allPagesData = $("#test1").DataTable().cells().nodes(); // this will give you all data in datatable.
  $(allPagesData).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd1aLv0n/)